# WCF OperationContract returning List<CustomType>

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WCF service that return a List.

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeesVM
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF to return the list of Employees to this class. In my WCF Service I'm using:

```
    public IList<EmployessVM> getEmployees()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new SecEntities())
        {
            return (from e in dbContext.Employees
                    select new EmployeesVM {
                       ID = e.ID,
                       Name = e.Name
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

In my Windows Phone 8 client app, I need to get the List from the method.

```
    void proxy_getEmployeesCompleted(object sender, GetDataService.getEmployeesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            List<ViewModel.EmployeesVM> resultList = e.Result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

In my WP ViewModel folder I have the same type:

```
public class EmployeesVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But, when I try to compile I get this error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type      'System.Collections.Generic.List<SisSeguranca.GetDataService.EmployeesVM>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SisSeguranca.ViewModel.EmployeesVM>'
```

And I've tried this too, and doesn't worked too.

```
 List<ViewModel.EmployeesVM> lista = (ViewModel.EmployeesVM)e.Result.ToList();
```

How can I convert the type returned in WCF service in my client app type that have the same fields and name ?

Comment: Either use the same type, both in client and service, or use a mapping library. For me, I usually return a DTO class which is present on both server and client, and is mapped to an entity class in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe You created service reference using Visual Studio Add Service Reference option. That will create proxy classes for your WCF service. It also appears that you have a similar class already existing/referenced in your project. That is why you are getting the error. There is an option to reuse existing types. Enable that.

See: [How to: Configure a Service to Reuse Existing Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx)

[image]

Another option is to separate contracts and related entities in a separate project

See: [Things to Consider When Designing a WCF Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273127(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The first recommendation is to separate logically related interfaces,
>   contracts, entities, messages, and enumerations into a separate
>   project. One way to do this is to add a class library project to your
>   solution and name it after your service name, with the word
>   "Contracts" appended to it. An example of this is
>   WcfService1.Contracts.

You can reference that dll/project in your WCF service as well as your project consuming the service.

Comment: +1 But you could also mention that it's best practice when sharing objects between service and client like this to move the `DataContract` objects into their own assembly for ease of use in this process.

Comment: @toadflakz, that is a good suggestion, added that to the answer with a reference.

Comment: @Habib I've created a Class Library (Portable) and added my class to this project and added the reference between projects and re-create the Service Reference. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two classes called "EmployeesVM" What you need to do is pull this class out into a DLL that is shared by your "Server" and Windows Phone.

Comment: That's not even needed. Using proper setup of the WCF, you can use the class used by your WCF service in your local model as well. If you start with the default WCF project from Visual Studio, this is already included. You then just need to add the webservice as a service reference in your project.